# Runtime of two nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I am calculating the run time complexity of the below Python code as `n^2` but it seems that it is incorrect. The correct answer shown is `n(n-1)/2`. Can anyone help help me in understanding why the inner loop is not running `n*n` times but rather `n(n-1)/2`?

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i):
        val += 1
```

Comment: Because it's not starting from 0 each time.  It's starting from `i`.  As `i` gets larger, the `j` loop runs fewer and fewer times.  HOWEVER, the runtime complexity of this code IS O(N**2).  Constants (like the -1 and the /2) are irrelevant in big-O complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first run of the inner loop, when `i = 0`, the `for` loop does not execute at all. (There are zero elements to iterate over in `range(0)`).

On the second run of the inner loop, when `i = 1`, the `for` loop executes for one iteration. (There is one element to iterate over in `range(1)`).

Then, there are two elements in the third run, three in the fourth, following this pattern, up until `i = n - 1`.

The total number of iterations is `0 + 1 + ... + (n - 1)`. This summation has a well known form*: for any natural `m`, `0 + 1 + ... + m = m * (m + 1) / 2`. In this case, we have `m = n - 1`, so there are `n * (n - 1) / 2` iterations in total.

You're right that the asymptotic time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n^2)`. However, given that you've said that the "correct answer" is `n * (n - 1) / 2`, the question most likely asked for the exact number of iterations (rather than an asymptotic bound).

---

<sub>* See [here](https://wiki.math.ucr.edu/index.php/An_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Induction:_The_Sum_of_the_First_n_Natural_Numbers,_Squares_and_Cubes.#The_Sum_of_the_first_n_Natural_Numbers) for a proof of this closed form.</sub>